# Unable to Create New Project in jekyll in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, markdown, jekyll

I have installed jekyll using jekyll [installation procedure](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/) on ubuntu 14.04 lts

After that to verify that it is Installed i run the following commands and get this,

```
jekyll -v and gets 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
Jekyll 0.11.2

gem -v and gets 
1.8.23 

ruby -v and gets 
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]


jekyll new blog

/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
WARNING: Could not read configuration. Using defaults (and options).
    No such file or directory - new/_config.yml
Building site: new -> blog
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/site.rb:126:in `chdir': No such file or directory - /home/muhammadtaqi/Projects/Open_Source/new/ (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/site.rb:126:in `read_directories'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/site.rb:98:in `read'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/site.rb:38:in `process'
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:250:in `<main>'
```